# How is Meteor's withTracker function executed differently than the former reactive container function createContainer?

Tags: javascript, meteor

The following is an example of `withTracker()` function call which includes usage of sequential parentheses in Javascript.

```
export default withTracker(props => {
    const handle = Meteor.subscribe('todoList', props.id);
    return {
        currentUser: Meteor.user(),
        listLoading: !handle.ready(),
        tasks: Tasks.find({ listId: props.id }).fetch(),
    };
})(Foo);
```

The former reactive container for React components in Meteor was the `createContainer()` function and it was called like the following for the same purpose of the above one.

```
export default FooContainer = createContainer(props => {
  const handle = Meteor.subscribe('todoList', props.id);
  return {
    currentUser: Meteor.user(),
    listLoading: ! handle.ready(),
    tasks: Tasks.find({ listId: props.id }).fetch(),
  };
}, Foo);
```

What is the difference in the execution of these two functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference at their execution, because `withTracker` is just a wrapper for `createContainer` call:

From [`meteor:react-packages` source code](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/blob/master/packages/react-meteor-data/withTracker.jsx#L3):

```js
const withTracker = fn => C => createContainer(fn, C);
```

Or, if you prefer:

```js
function withTracker(fn) {
  return function(C) {
    return createContainer(fn, C);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the 2 possible syntaxes you can use,showing a function+variable being passed in.

```
const someContainer = withTracker((props) => ({
  someFunction(parms) { ..function code },
  someVariable: value,
}))(ComponentName);
```

or

```
const someContainer = withTracker((props) => {
  const someFunction = (parms) => { ..function code };
  const someVariable = value;
  return {
    someFunction,
    someVariable,
  }
})(ComponentName);
```

You typically need the second as you'll be setting data subscriptions before passing ('returning') them to the component, but sometimes the first 'shortcut' syntax is useful when you just want to pass some existing things in to the component.