# Jest Testing Meteor React Component which is using withTracker in Container (meteor/react-meteor-data)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, jestjs

I am testing component using `withTracker` in its container.

An error happens:

> TypeError: (0 , _reactMeteorData.withTracker) is not a function.

I think I haven't mock the react-meteor-data/withTracker yet. Can someone tell me how to mock it? Or is there any solution for this?

Comment: It has been quite a while, but how have you solved this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [How is Meteor's withTracker function executed differently than the former reactive container function createContainer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632408/how-is-meteors-withtracker-function-executed-differently-than-the-former-reacti)
I managed to upgrade the tests from createContainer to withTracker using the following:

In your mocked react-meteor-data.js file.

```
const createContainer = jest.fn((options = {}, component) => component );

const withTracker = jest.fn(Op => jest.fn(C => createContainer(Op, C)));
```

Then export withTracker instead of createContainer.